# How to test forwarded ref in React using test renderer or enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-test-renderer

I use some amount of animations in my application and all animations depend on the refs (I am using GSAP). Most of the tested elements are located in other React components; so, I have set up `forwardRef` in my components to to pass the ref to the needed elements.

Now, I want to test these refs using Jest and Enzyme or React Test Renderer but I have not been able to achieve it with both the libraries. Here is my current implementation:

```
it('passes refs to the container component', () => {
    const ref = React.createRef();
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(<Row ref={ref} />, div);

    const element = div.querySelector('div');
    expect(element).toBe(ref.current);
});
```

Using `ReactTestRenderer.create` or `enzyme.render` to do a full rendering does not work because the refs are empty. Then, I found `enzyme.mount` function, which does something similar to `ReactDOM.render`; so, decided to use that:

```
it('passes refs to the container component', () => {
    const ref = React.createRef();
    const wrapper = mount(<Row ref={ref} />);
    const div = wrapper.find('div').first().getDOMNode();
    expect(div).toBe(ref.current);
});
```

This test does not pass because for some reason, the `div` returns HTMLElement while `ref.current` return something called WrapperComponent instead of returning the forwarded element.

Creating element and using ReactDOM to render and test the ref works fine but I would want to know if there is a way to use enzyme or react test renderer for this purpose (I am not a fan of using multiple libraries for rendering to test different functionalities).

The main reason I want to to test refs is because if a ref changes to another element in the component, all the animations that use the component's ref will break. So, I want to specify what elements are accessed when using refs.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `ref.current.getDomNode()`.

Comment: It is better to be sure while you provide an answer.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more?